# Neo4j: REST API Cypher Query to find relationship between two nodes

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I'm new to Neo4j and am using REST API's to create nodes and relationships. I've two nodes NA and NB and they are connected w/ a relationship RC. 'NA - RC - NB'. Before I create the nodes and the relationship, I check to see if the nodes and the relationship between them do not exist. I figure out how to check if a node exists and am struggling w/ how to check if a relationship between the two nodes exist. I came up w/ this Cypher query.

```
"start x  = node(*), n = node(*) 
match x-[r]->n 
where (x.name? = {from} and type(r) = {rtype} and n.name? = {to}) 
return ID(r), TYPE(r)"
```

The nodes have a property 'name'. I'm getting empty 'data: []' when I execute this query.

Any suggestions? I tried looking into the Neo4j documentation and some tutorial but not quite able to figure this out.

TIA

Here is the java code:

```
/** Check if a relationship exists between two nodes */
public boolean relationshipExists(String from /** node name */
, String to /** node name */
, String type) {
    boolean exists = false;

    /** check if relationship exists */
    String url = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher";
    JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("from", from);
        params.put("rtype", type);
        params.put("to", to);
        String query = "start x  = node(*), n = node(*) match x-[r]->n where (x.name? = {from} and type(r) = {rtype} and n.name? = {to}) return ID(r), TYPE(r)";
        jobject.put("query", query);
        jobject.put("params", params);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        logger.error("Error", e);
    }

    String response = sendQuery(url, jobject.toString());

    try {
        jobject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray data = (JSONArray) jobject.get("data");
        JSONArray next = null;
        for (int index = 0; index < data.length(); index++) {
            next = data.getJSONArray(index);
            if (!next.isNull(1) && next.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                exists = (next.getInt(0) > -1) ? true : false;
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        logger.error("Error", e);
    }

    return exists;
}
```

Comment: That looks like it would work, although it might be quicker to use indexes on the name field so you can start at the node without having to scan the whole graph. Can you provide some more code--especially the part where you pass the map of parameters?

Comment: You are probably right because when I take out the where clause I'm getting results that include the relationship I'm looking for and there is something wrong w/ the where clause that I'm unable to put my finger on. Thanks for the indexing suggestion too, I wanted to add it after my basic functionality worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type parameter is listed as `{type}`, but defined as `"rtype"` in the parameter map. Does that fix it for you? You might try the query without the parameters (just hard code them in), to see if it works.

Comment: Good catch. I've tried so many changes around the query and ended up using type instead of rtype. There was a couple of other things I was doing wrong w.r.t to the input. Your previous and current hints certainly helped me think and fix my problem. Thanks for the help again.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could make it different with the RELATE command:
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.8.M03/query-relate.html

this way there is no need to check whether or not the relation already exists. simply, if it doesn't then it creates one.